# Selecting reoccurring values

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe:

```
Group   Name  Pop
A         F     5
A         C     4
A         D     4
B         E     6
B         L     4
```

I need a dataframe in which only data remains where there is at least three names in one group. 
So output:

```
Group  Name  Pop
A        F     5
A        C     4
A        D     4
```

I figured the easiest way would be to group by Group where group value count is three or more. I've tried different ways, always some errors.

```
df['Group'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()>2)  #for example this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupby` way to do this is groupby by 'Group' and then `filter`:

```
In [6]:

df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: x['Name'].count() > 2)
Out[6]:
  Group Name  Pop
0     A    F    5
1     A    C    4
2     A    D    4
```

The above doesn't discount duplicate names, if you want a count of unique names of 3 or more then you can filter using [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas.Series.nunique):

```
In [7]:

df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: x['Name'].nunique() > 2)
Out[7]:
  Group Name  Pop
0     A    F    5
1     A    C    4
2     A    D    4
```